# class similar to pipe in C# for inter thread communication

Tags: c#, stream, pipe

Are there any classes in the .Net framework which implement pipes, but for inter thread communication instead of interprocess communication? `System.IO.Pipes` seems overkill.

Specifically what I'm looking for is something that allows a single reader thread and a single writer thread, and allows blocking IO on both the read and write sides of the pipe. `System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream` seems overboard.

Additionally, ideally, the writer would be able to "write" exceptions to the pipe, which would cause any reader to wake up, and any additional reads would throw the exception "pushed" through the pipe.

Note that I'm looking for something that implements the `System.IO.Stream` interfaces. I'm strictly trying to send a stream of data, not necessarily "messages". The reason for wanting a stream interface, is that I would like the reader to be able to treat the incoming data like any other source.

Comment: Pipes are streams and you can use a MemoryStream for thread communications.  Exceptions would be application level messaging.

Comment: Does one of the synchronized collections match your requirements? Think of the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx namespace

Comment: If you need inter thread, what about event aggregator https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: Why do you keep saying that `System.IO.Pipes` is overkill?  `AnonymousPipeClientStream` and `AnonymousPipeServerStream` stream seem to perfectly fit your requirements (except for your exception requirement--you'd have to model that explicitly).  I suggest you give them a try and get on with your solution and only worry about them being "overkill" when you have some metrics that show them to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Monitor. It has a [Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait(v=vs.110).aspx#) method for the reader and a [Pulse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx) method for the writer.

Communication is done via  the object that is passed as an argument.